# App crashes when tested on iPhone, but not in simulator

Tags: ios, json, iphone, swift, twitter

I have a code that fetches a JSON from twitter and puts it into a struct called `feedStruct` but also parses it to the UITableViewController.

I have tested it multiple times in the simulator but wanted to test it on my iPhone as well, and then it crashes in this piece of code. I have made a comment next to the line that "makes the app crash":

> Thread 8: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

(I think it at some point said Thread 6 too thought, if that has anything to do with it.)

Here is the code:

```
import Foundation

protocol twitterModelProtocol: class {
    func twitterDownloaded(items: [Any])
    func feedTwitterDatesDownloaded(items: [feedStruct])
}

class twitterModel: NSObject {

    //properties
    weak var delegate: twitterModelProtocol!

    let urlPath = "http://MYWEBPAGE/twit.php" //this will be changed to the path where service.php lives

    func downloadTwitterItems() {
        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Failed to download twitter data")
            } else {
                print("Twitter data downloaded")
                self.parseTwitterJSON(data!)
            }
        }    
        task.resume()
    }

    func parseTwitterJSON(_ data:Data) {
        var jsonResult = [Any]()

        do{
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [Any]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }

        var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
        var feeds = [feedStruct]()

        for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count {
            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

            let feed = feedStruct()
            //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
            if let unixstamp = jsonElement["created_at"] as? String {

                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"

                print(unixstamp)

                let date = dateFormatter.date(from: unixstamp)! //THIS LINE IS MAKING THE APP CRASH ON iPHONE NOT SIMULATOR <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                let calendar = Calendar.current
                let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour], from: date)
                let finalDate = calendar.date(from:components)

                let timestamp = finalDate?.timeIntervalSince1970
                let finalTimestamp = String(format: "%.0f", timestamp!)

                feed.date = finalTimestamp
                feed.type = "twitter"   
            }
            feeds.append(feed)   
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            self.delegate.twitterDownloaded(items: jsonResult)
            self.delegate.feedTwitterDatesDownloaded(items: feeds)  
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Something is nil, find out which var is nil.

Comment: Why make your class inherit from `NSObject`? This is not Objective-C, classes don't need to have a base class. You also shouldn't be using `NSDictionary`, use its native Swift counterpart, `Dictionary` (more specifically, `Dictionary<String:Any>` when working with JSON data). `catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }` is also unnecessary, you can simply do `catch {print(error)}`, an `error` variable is automatically provided by the `catch` block. You should also pinpoint the error to a single line by setting up an exception breakpoint in the debugger.

Comment: what is printed on the device with the `unixstamp`?

Comment: The date as it should - which is even weirder @MilanNosáľ

Comment: check my answer, and if it does not help, copy paste the result of printing `unixstamp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set following (the date/time settings of the device might cause discrepancy between simulator and device):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "GMT")
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: unixstamp) else {
    // deal with non-existent date
}
```

Comment: shouldn't use `!` at all, thats what causes the crash in the first place. what if the next request returns nil for `created_at`?. The app should be able to fail gracefully. once it can do that and not crash, find out why it's not getting the desired value

Comment: @Scriptable if next call returns `nil` for `created_at`, the whole part won't execute (it is already in `if let`), the only problem can cause the format.. but yeah, it is better to deal with optionals gracefully..

Comment: @D.Finna Sure.. but be careful about the implicit uwrapping - `!`, it's better to user either `?` or `if let` to make sure your app won't crash. You can use it in development mode and while testing - crash during development makes it easier for you to realize something is wrong, but in production you want to use safe operations..